# display-shell-version C-x C-v for zsh

Tags: bash, version, keyboard-shortcuts, zsh

In bash, pressing `C-x` `C-v` outputs the version of the shell, e.g.

```
$ # pressing C-x C-v here
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
```

In zsh, nothing happens. The same applies to other "standard" bash keycombos like `C-x` `C-e` to start the default `$EDITOR`.

```
% # pressing C-x C-v here - nothing happens
% zsh --version
zsh 5.3.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
% # ^ I want to the above line output on C-x C-v
```

What is the easiest way to enable these bash keycombos for zsh?

Answer (score 2):

in `zshrc` file add:

```
autoload -U edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey '\C-x\C-e' edit-command-line
```

now u can start editor. 
in `bash` for show version there is `display-shell-version`:

```
display-shell-version (C-x C-v)
              Display version information about the current instance of bash.
```

in `zsh` there is not display-shell-version, but u can create your function and after make binding